# Return value from Spring to Angular

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, http, post

I want a microservice in Spring to return a value that can identify if it's user or admin to Angular.
I have only succeded to return a boolean value but I don't know how to change it to work with strings (I could use whatever data type I want), for example I thought of returning a ResponseEntity but it didn't work.
Thank you in advance.
This is my code:

APIGatewayApplication.java:

```
switch(jsonString){
            case "admin":
                //return new ResponseEntity<>("admin", HttpStatus.OK);
                return true;
            case "user":
                return true;
                //return new ResponseEntity<>("user", HttpStatus.OK);
            default:
                return false;
                //return new ResponseEntity<>("None", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

login-form.component.ts:

```
login() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/login';
    this.http.post<Observable<boolean>>(url, {
    username: this.model.username,
    password: this.model.password
}).subscribe(isValid => {
    if (isValid) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(
          'token', 
          btoa(this.model.username + ':' + this.model.password)
        );
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/actions', { state: { username: this.model.username , role:'user' } });
        } else {
            alert("Authentication failed.")
        }  
    });
  }
```

Comment: Don't you need to change `Observable<boolean>` to `Observable<String>`?

Comment: But I think that the isValid parameter that I have used can only be used with boolean observable, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `isAdmin` field in your `user` model and you can set `isAdmin` to `1` when it is an Admin user and to `0` when it is a simple user. You will use the value of this field in your `login-form.component.ts`

Comment: But i find whether is a user or an admin in spring, I have to let angular know if it's one of them or if it's none of them, meaning that the login has failed

Comment: Why do you use a Observable<boolean> in your post  to verify the values of username and password ?

Comment: You are right, I didn't need it. I have solved it using this.http.post<number>